# I weight about 40 lbs (18 kg) more than the weight limit for the trike I can afford

Tags: weight, tricycle

I want to get an adult tricycle because I have balance problems, but I think that a triking/biking would be a good way to help get my weight under control. I weight about 40 pounds more than the advertised weight limit for the trike I can afford. How bad is the risk? I wouldn't be biking too fast. Just a couple miles a day.

Comment: Are you able to (or comfortable) sharing the model of trike you were considering? Also, Criggie's idea below about trying a spin bike is a good one. They're very stable with heavy bases, plus if your goal is weight loss, you could try spin classes were are pretty intense cardio. More intense than most beginner cyclists can make themselves go on their own on a bike.

Comment: I was looking at the Schwinn Meridian Adult Trike https://www.walmart.com/ip/24-Schwinn-Meridian-Adult-Tricycle/21188122

Answer (score 6):

**Answer**: Maybe - speed isn't the problem.

While most "limits" have generous tolerances, your manufacturer's warranty could be unusable if there was a structural problem.

Your brakes would have to dispel more momentum while stopping, so that will increase wear and runout distances.

Riding is a great way to get exercise, and I've successfully ridden road bikes while being at the upper boundary of weight.

---

Suggestion: can you try a spin bike at a gym?  Could give you the cycling motion without needing to be on a bike at all.  They are heavy, solid and stable so you're not going to fall off.

Comment: Imho, using a spin bike pretty much defeats everything that makes biking fun: a) being outdoors b) feeling the slip-wind c) seeing nature d) feeling the connection between effort and speed e) the fun of the occasional downhill road f) riding past traffic jammed cars. I can do 200km per week on a bike, but I can't do 10km per week on a spin bike. The later just feels too much like stupid work, while the former is pure fun.

Comment: @cmaster I totally agree they're boring to ride - the stationary bike was to help OP get started on the way to a weight where the trike will be within posted weight limits.   On the plus side, a stationary bike can be used at home if you can find one cheap enough on ebay or craigslist.  They can also be leased/rented.